# Bootstrap multilevel submenu on top

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I keep all the submenus always on top as well as the first? I tried to insert a container but I was not successful ...

Forgive me if there is a similar topic, but I could not find that specific problem.

I'm using the bootstrap in this example.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/10838/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="brand">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#">More options</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-left">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query span2">
          </form>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="#" href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#">More options</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Another action</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS (your submenu dropdown menus will be relative to your main dropdown menu instead of the submenu element):

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: static;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/10839/)